# How to compute =SUM(Above) function in docx using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I am trying to work with apache poi for docx format file and I am stuck at using formulas in table. For instance see the image :

[image: Word Screenshot]

I did try setting text to "=SUM(ABOVE)" but it doesnt work this way.
  I think I might need to set custom xml data here but I am not sure how to proceed. I tried following piece of code :

```
              XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
              //create first row
              XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
              table.getRow(0).createCell();
              table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setText("10");
              table.getRow(0).createCell();
              table.getRow(0).getCell(1).setText("=SUM(ABOVE)");
```

Comment: Use Excel instead? That's designed for working with numbers and formulas in tables, Word isn't....

Comment: But we have inbuilt functions in docx(microsoft). Adding a link for reference here. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-a-column-or-row-of-numbers-in-a-table-2e373a5f-2d8a-478a-9b85-275c8668bebb

Comment: Your screen shot shows not `Microsoft Word` but `LibreOffice Writer`. `LibreOffice Writer` is not able storing such formula fields into `*.docx` format nor is it able reading such `*.docx` formula fields properly. So your question only would be answerable when `Microsoft Word` is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am doing in case of such requirements is as follows:
First, creating the simplest possible `Word` document having the required things in it using the `Word` `GUI`. Then have a look into what `Word` has created to get a idea what needs to be created using `apache poi`.

In concrete here:
Do creating the simplest possible table in `Word` which has a field `{=SUM(ABOVE)}` in it. Save that as `*.docx`. Now unzip that `*.docx` (Office Open XML files like `*.docx` are simply `ZIP` archive). Have a look at `/word/document.xml` in that archive. There you will find something like:

```
<w:tc>
 <w:p>
  <w:fldSimple w:instr="=SUM(ABOVE)"/>
 ...
 </w:p>
</w:tc>
```

This is `XML` for a table cell having a paragraph having a `fldSimple` element in it where `instr` attribute contains the formula.

Now we know, we need the table cell `XWPFTableCell` and the `XWPFParagraph` in it. Then we need set a  `fldSimple` element in this paragaraph where `instr` attribute contains the formula.

This would be as simple as

```
paragraphInCell.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("=SUM(ABOVE)");
```

But of course something must tell `Word` the need to calculate the formula when the document opens. The simplest solution for this is setting the field "dirty". That leads to the need for updating the field while opening the document in `Word`. It also leads to a confirming message dialog about the need for updating.

Complete example using `apache poi 4.1.0`:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSimpleField;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff;

public class CreateWordTableSumAbove {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The table:");

  //create the table
  XWPFTable table = document.createTable(4,3);
  table.setWidth("100%");
  for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
   for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
    if (col < 2) table.getRow(row).getCell(col).setText("row " + row + ", col " + col);
    else table.getRow(row).getCell(col).setText("" + ((row + 1) * 1234));
   }
  }

  //set Sum row
  table.getRow(3).getCell(0).setText("Sum:");

  //get paragraph from cell where the sum field shall be contained
  XWPFParagraph paragraphInCell = null;
  if (table.getRow(3).getCell(2).getParagraphs().size() == 0) paragraphInCell = table.getRow(3).getCell(2).addParagraph();
  else paragraphInCell = table.getRow(3).getCell(2).getParagraphs().get(0);

  //set sum field in
  CTSimpleField sumAbove = paragraphInCell.getCTP().addNewFldSimple();
  sumAbove.setInstr("=SUM(ABOVE)");
  //set sum field dirty, so it must be calculated while opening the document
  sumAbove.setDirty(STOnOff.TRUE);

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("create_table.docx"); 
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

That all only works properly when the document is opened using `Microsoft Word`. `LibreOffice Writer` is not able storing such formula fields into `Office Open XML` (`*.docx`) format nor is it able reading such `Office Open XML` formula fields properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Axel. Really appreciate it. But when I run the file it prompt me  with : This document contains links that may refer to other files.

Comment: This is the mentioned confirming message dialog about the need for updating. Press [Yes] if you wants the field to be updated.

Comment: Thanks Axel. Anyway we can skip that ?

Comment: Only if the sum field would be created having the current value cached. Do the steps of first  part of my answer to see how then  XML` then must look like. But that would need the code to calculate the sum instead of delegating that to `Word`.

Comment: Axel - You are legend. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: If we use above method and then try to convert pdf or html via code - will that result in actual sum or is there any other way to do this.

Comment: @Piyush Kalra: No, that is a field which only gets calculated when `Word` renders the document.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So only way to go forward is to manually calculate it right ?

Comment: @Piyush Kalra: Correct.

Comment: Last thing. Thanks for everything. How can i write code for something like this:<w:r w:rsidRPr="0035277E"><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" /><w:color w:val="424242" /><w:spacing w:val="1" /><w:sz w:val="24" /><w:szCs w:val="24" /></w:rPr><w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> =SUM(ABOVE) </w:instrText></w:r>

Comment: can you check above comment ?

Comment: @Piyush Kalra: This is not how StackOverflow works. If you have a new question, please ask a new question. Code is nothing what can be discussed in comments. And please be more specific in what you want to achieve.

Comment: Added a new question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61777439/sumabove-functionality-in-apache-poi-or-docx4j

Comment: How can i set the sum(above) to bold ?

Comment: @Piyush Kalra: Not possible using this solution as formatting is only possible for text runs. But in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61777439/sumabove-functionality-in-apache-poi-or-docx4j you've got an answer which used a text run for the cached value. This also can be formatted then: `sumAbove.getRArray(0).addNewRPr().addNewB();`.