# Apache docx CreateWatermark Set font in text oR CTTextPath setstyle remove double/single quotes

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I am using the code from here by extending this calss
https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xwpf/model/XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.java?view=markup#l416

COde from this :`CTTextPath shapeTextPath = shape.addNewTextpath(); shapeTextPath.setStyle("font-family:&quot;Cambria&quot;;font-size:1pt");`

Tried various combination and permutation but in the end in xml it removes it and prints like  :

```
<v:textpath style="font-family:Cambria;font-size:1pt" string="test"/>
```

Any help is needed. should be like this

```
<v:textpath style="font-family:'Cambria';font-size:1pt" string="test"/>
```