# Is it possible to update a cell with formula of a table in word document?

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi

Does anyone know if it is possible to update the cells with formulas of a table in a word document?

I know it is possible to do this with an excel document but I can't find a way to do something similar with a table in a word document.

Comment: You mean Word tables containing formula fields? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57261914/how-to-compute-sumabove-function-in-docx-using-apache-poi/57270793#57270793 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61777439/sumabove-functionality-in-apache-poi-or-docx4j.

Comment: @AxelRichter 
Yes, it is a table that has a cell to calculate the column total with this formula '=SUM(ABOVE)'. I just saw the links. I will calculate the column sum and remove the formula. Thanks for the help.

Comment: SUM(ABOVE) and its like are unreliable. For an explanation and resolution, check out my **Microsoft Word Field Maths Tutorial**, at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38720-microsoft-word-field-maths-tutorial.html